# fail2ban blocks ip twice for some reason

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I have a file of blacklisted IPs that get loaded through `fail2ban` into `iptables` when `fail2ban` starts up.

Assuming the initial list looks like this at startup:

```
Chain fail2ban-ip-blacklist (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  120.25.68.125        0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                      

Chain fail2ban-wordress (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Why would I get a notification in my logs after startup that `120.25.68.125` has been banned and revisit the iptables status to see this:

```
Chain fail2ban-ip-blacklist (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  120.25.68.125        0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                      

Chain fail2ban-wordress (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  120.25.68.125        0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Shouldn't the IP `120.25.68.125` already be blocked and not need to be re-added to the ban list? Why is traffic from `120.25.68.125` being let back through?

### Update: Full `iptables` output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1393 packets, 164K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1401  164K fail2ban-wordpress  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1410  165K fail2ban-repeatoffender  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1207 packets, 1786K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-repeatoffender (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       120.25.68.125        0.0.0.0/0                   

Chain fail2ban-wordpress (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1401  164K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Implies that your blacklist chain isn't working. You probably need to include output of iptables -l -v (from memory)

Comment: I added the full output (`iptables -L -v`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of the `fail2ban-wordpress` and `fail2ban-repeatoffender` rules in your `INPUT` chain.